# How to Create Object Class for GSON parsing in Android for following JSON string?

Tags: android, json, gson

```
{
"errorDesc": "",
"ownerId": 2096,

"departments": "Asset Protection,Backroom Flow,Bakery,Clinic,Dairy,Deli,Distribution (Communication),Facilities Management,Frozen,Guest Experience,Human Resources,Instocks,Meat,Optical,POG and Adjacencies,Pharmacy,Photo Lab,Portrait Studio,Presentation,Price Accuracy,Produce/Floral,Remodel,Reverse Logistics,Sales Floor: A&A,Sales Floor: Grocery,Sales Floor: Hardlines,Sales Floor: Health & Beauty,Sales Floor: Home,Signing and Fixtures,Starbucks,Store,Target Cafe",

"validUser": "Y",
"clientId": "TGT",
"displayPrio": "Y",
"allowSimpleProject": "Y",
"simpleProjectType": "SIM",
"reqDept": {
    "STORE_AP": "Asset Protection",
    "STORE_BF": "Backroom Flow",
    "STORE_BAKERY": "Bakery",
    "STORE_CLINIC": "Clinic",
    "STORE_DAIRY": "Dairy",
    "STORE_DELI": "Deli",
    "STORE_DISTRIBUTI": "Distribution (Communication)",
    "STORE_FM": "Facilities Management",
    "STORE_FROZEN": "Frozen",
    "STORE_GE": "Guest Experience",
    "STORE_HR": "Human Resources",
    "STORE_INSTOCKS": "Instocks",
    "STORE_MEAT": "Meat",
    "STORE_OPTICAL": "Optical",
    "STORE_POG": "POG and Adjacencies",
    "STORE_PHARM": "Pharmacy",
    "STORE_PL": "Photo Lab",
    "STORE_PS": "Portrait Studio",
    "STORE_PRESENTATI": "Presentation",
    "STORE_PA": "Price Accuracy",
    "STORE_PROD": "Produce/Floral",
    "STORE_REMODEL": "Remodel",
    "STORE_RL": "Reverse Logistics",
    "STORE_AA": "Sales Floor: A&A",
    "STORE_GROC": "Sales Floor: Grocery",
    "STORE_SFH": "Sales Floor: Hardlines",
    "STORE_HB": "Sales Floor: Health & Beauty",
    "STORE_HOME": "Sales Floor: Home",
    "STORE_SIGNFIX": "Signing and Fixtures",
    "STORE_STARBUCKS": "Starbucks",
    "STORE": "Store",
    "STORE_TC": "Target Cafe"
},

"viewOptions": null,
"sessionId": "c170be7b-81a3-4d95-a204-af72d166d28e",
"unitName": "MPLS-NICOLLET MALL",
"userId": "dderr-st",
"userName": "Dan Derr - Store",
"errorCd": "0",
"profiles": "STL/Store Team Lead,Specialist",
"view": "",
"unitId": "1375"
}
```

Can somebody plz help ..how to create Object class for above JSON string

so that i can achieve this -
 Gson gson = new Gson();

```
        Register register_class = gson.fromJson(registration_response,Register.class);           
         register_list.add(register_class);
```

Comment: You want a class that matches that JSON so that you can deserialize it? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to create class to match JOSN.  but in that class i have just create usefull object of   getter and setter. on this approach i am getting  Exception :::::  GSON returning Exception json syntax exception expected a string but was begin_object at line 1 column 15

Answer (score 1):

Although I strongly recommend educating yourself on the structure of JSON and how it translates to standard Java objects. There are tools that automatically generate classes from JSON. These tools are note always reliable, though! One of them is:

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

If you are going to learn the JSON structure keep this format in mind:

{"fieldName":"value"}

This translates to:

```
class RootClass
{
    private String fieldName;
    public String getFieldName() {
       return fieldName;
    }

    public void setFieldName(String fieldName) {
       this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }
}
```

Where fieldName will get the value: 'value'.

Comment: hi tim,  How can i get only useful fields from json string in class format .... i dont want whole string to be my class ..only useful ...how can i do that ? any idea ?

Comment: Simply only add the field that you need, the GSON library automatically skips a field as soon as it is not declared in the class.

Answer (score 1):

Your class should look something like: (I say something like because I marked as Strings fields that I was not sure what you want them to be)

```
public class MyClass {
    private String errorDesc;
    private Integer ownerId;
    private String departments;
    private String validUser;
    private String clientId;
    private String displayPrio;
    private String allowSimpleProject;
    private String simpleProjectType;
    private ReqDept reqDept;
    private String viewOptions;
    private String sessionId;
    private String unitName;
    private String userid;
    private String userName;
    private String errorCd;
    private String profiles;
    private String view;
    private Integer unitId;

    class ReqDept {
        private String STORE_API;
        private String STORE_BF;
        private String STORE_BAKERY;
        private String STORE_CLINIC;
        private String STORE_DAIRY;
        private String STORE_DELI;
        private String STORE_DISTRIBUTI;
        private String STORE_FM;
        private String STORE_FROZEN;
        private String STORE_GE;
        private String STORE_HR;
        private String STORE_INSTOCKS;
        private String STORE_MEAT;
        private String STORE_OPTICAL;
        private String STORE_POG;
        private String STORE_PHARM;
        private String STORE_PL;
        private String STORE_PS;
        private String STORE_PRESENTATI;
        private String STORE_PA;
        private String STORE_PROD;
        private String STORE_REMODEL;
        private String STORE_RL;
        private String STORE_AA;
        private String STORE_GROC;
        private String STORE_SFH;
        private String STORE_HB;
        private String STORE_HOME;
        private String STORE_SIGNFIX;
        private String STORE_STARBUCKS;
        private String STORE;
        private String STORE_TC;
}
```

You also need to generate getters and setters for both the fields in `MyClass` and fields inside the inner `ReqDept` class. The `ReqDept` class is required because the information you are getting inside that JSON field is another JSON object.

Also, be careful with the *"Y"* values, because they will not be automatically casted to `boolean` (that's why I marked them as Strings).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You Should Use GsonFormat Plugin in Android Studio which can convert json string into Java OBject For Gson

go to file -> setting -> plugin ->Browse Repositories -> search GsonFormat

and download and restart the android studio

Now, go to getter setter class and press alt + s and put json string into opened window, then click ok or go to setting for more options

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post on `JSON` parsing using `GSON` and native technic I wrote:

[JSON Parsing using GSON guide](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=746)

There is a sample project at the end of the guide you can download and learn from as well.